# Selenium not navigating to a page I want it to

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping

I use Selenium to scrape data from a web game, where to navigate on site I need to type in the URLs manually, then refresh (the data won't show otherwise)

````
driver.execute_script('''window.open("https://rivalregions.com/#listed/country/-2/0/hospital", "_self");''')```
driver.execute_script('''window.location.reload();''')
````

The above code worked fine, but recently instead of refreshing the page and displaying the data, it simply just changes the url back to https://rivalregions.com/#overview, which is the main page.

The problem is only present when running the script in headless mode. GUI works perfectly fine.

Comment: See if switching to that tab and running driver.refresh() works.

Comment: It doesn't unfortunately, it also goes back to that overview page

Comment: @MeT playwright works, thank you a lot!

Comment: Added like an answer maybe for some one else it will be useful. Mark it like a correct answer if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Playwright](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro) you have **3 browsers** with headless mode.
Maybe with webkit it will work.